# How to change the p_value of a t.test function

Tags: r

```
  amostra <- rnorm(27, mean = 1.1, 2.8)
  x <- t.test(amostra, mu = 0.3, alternative = "greater")
```

I have this code, but I am told that I need to test a H0: mu = 0.3 against H0: mu > 0.3, to the significance level of 0.04. I think they mean the p.value, but I have no idea how to change that

Comment: Are you aware that you can access the documentation for the `t.test` function using `?t.test()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `conf.level` argument, see `?t.test` for more details. The default is `conf.level = 0.95` which corresponds to alpha = 0.05 since confidence = 1 - alpha. So if you want significance level of 0.04 that corresponds to a `conf.level = 0.96`

```
x <- t.test(amostra, mu = 0.3, alternative = "greater",conf.level = 0.96)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One more question if that's okay, I want the probability of the non-regection of mu = 0.3, I've tried using an if statement adds 1 to a variable starting at 0, so that then I simply have to divide it by the sample size and I get the probability, but I don't know what argument from the t.test I should use in the if-statement.

Comment: @PedroAlmeida, please ask questions as questions, not as comments on answers :)

Comment: @PedroAlmeida Im not sure I understand what you mean, are you referring to the p value? the p-value is the probability that the null hypothesis is true. To get this you would use x$p.value

Comment: @cgvoller ohhhh yeah I get it now, sorry I was a bit confused, thank you so much!!